# Filter Listview from EditText is not updating itself

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to filter a listview on Android using an Edit Text.

Inside of my `afterTextChanged` of my TextWatcher, I am doing this: `cardBoxListViewAdapter.getFilter().filter(editable);`

Here is my adapter:

```
public class CardBoxListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CardBoxItems> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "CardBoxListAdapter";

    private ValueFilter valueFilter;
    ArrayList<CardBoxItems> cardBoxModelArrayList;
    ArrayList<CardBoxItems> cardBoxModelArrayList2;
    private Context context;

    public CardBoxListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CardBoxItems> cardBoxModelArrayList) {
        super(context, 0, cardBoxModelArrayList);
        this.cardBoxModelArrayList = cardBoxModelArrayList;
        this.cardBoxModelArrayList2 = cardBoxModelArrayList;
        this.context = context;

        getFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        final CardBoxItems cardBoxModel = getItem(position);

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_listview_cardbox, parent, false);

        }

        TextView searchedFor = view.findViewById(R.id.cardBoxTitle);
        String searchedForString = cardBoxModel.getSearchedFor().replace("+", " ");
        searchedFor.setText(searchedForString);


        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (charSequence != null && charSequence.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<CardBoxItems> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < cardBoxModelArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    if (cardBoxModelArrayList.get(i).getSearchedFor().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        filteredList.add(cardBoxModelArrayList.get(i));
                    }
                }
                results.count = filteredList.size();
                results.values = filteredList;
            } else {
                results.count = cardBoxModelArrayList.size();
                results.values = cardBoxModelArrayList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            cardBoxModelArrayList2 = (ArrayList<CardBoxItems>) filterResults.values;
            System.out.println(cardBoxModelArrayList2.size());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

The problem I am facing is that the bottom `println()` is showing the right size but the `listview` itself does not update. What is wrong with the code?

I created a second arraylist and then storing the filtered info in there, but that is also not working for me. I just can pinpoint the issue, which I way i came here in hopes to have some other eyes gives me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class CardBoxListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CardBoxItems> {
private static final String TAG = "CardBoxListAdapter";

private ValueFilter valueFilter;
ArrayList<CardBoxItems> cardBoxModelArrayList;  // list for display filtered items (initially all items).
ArrayList<CardBoxItems> cardBoxModelArrayList2; // list for backup (always contains all items).
private Context context;

public CardBoxListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CardBoxItems> cardBoxModelArrayList) {
    super(context, 0, cardBoxModelArrayList);
    this.cardBoxModelArrayList = cardBoxModelArrayList;
    // Note: cardBoxModelArrayList is used here, so getItem(position) will return item from
    // this list. Therefore filtered result should be put to this list.

    // this.cardBoxModelArrayList2 = cardBoxModelArrayList;
    // The above line is wrong, it makes backup list exactly same as display list.
    // They should be two different lists.
    cardBoxModelArrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    this.cardBoxModelArrayList2.addAll(cardBoxModelArrayList);

    this.context = context;
    //getFilter();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final CardBoxItems cardBoxModel = getItem(position);
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_listview_cardbox, parent, false);
    }
    TextView searchedFor = view.findViewById(R.id.cardBoxTitle);
    String searchedForString = cardBoxModel.getSearchedFor().replace("+", " ");
    searchedFor.setText(searchedForString);
    return view;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (valueFilter == null) {
        valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}

private class ValueFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (charSequence != null && charSequence.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<CardBoxItems> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < cardBoxModelArrayList2.size(); i++) {
                if (cardBoxModelArrayList2.get(i).getSearchedFor().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    filteredList.add(cardBoxModelArrayList2.get(i));
                }
            }
            results.count = filteredList.size();
            results.values = filteredList;
        } else {
            results.count = cardBoxModelArrayList2.size();
            results.values = cardBoxModelArrayList2;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        cardBoxModelArrayList.clear();
        cardBoxModelArrayList.addAll((ArrayList<CardBoxItems>) filterResults.values);
        System.out.println(cardBoxModelArrayList.size());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

}
```